# Is (map f) == concatMap (map f . (:[]))?

Tags: haskell, arrows

I defined the `left`/`right` methods for stream functions (SF) of the `ArrowChoice` class as follows:
`newtype SF a b = SF { runSF :: [a] -> [b] }`

```
instance ArrowChoice SF where
  left (SF f) =
   SF $ map (either (\x -> Left . head $ f [x]) Right)
  right (SF f) =
   SF $ map (either Left (\x -> Right . head $ f [x]))
```

A few tests in ghci makes it seem like everything is fine:

```
λ> let lst = [Left 'c', Right 2, Left 'a', Right 3, Left 't']
λ> let foo = SF $ map toUpper
λ> let bar = SF $ map (+1)
λ> runSF (left foo) lst
[Left 'C',Right 2,Left 'A',Right 3,Left 'T']
λ> runSF (right bar) lst
[Left 'c',Right 3,Left 'a',Right 4,Left 't']
```

But using it with `mapA` says otherwise:

```
λ> let delay x = SF $ init . (x:)
λ> runSF (mapA (delay 0)) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

The correct answer should be:

```
[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

where mapA is defined as:

```
mapA :: ArrowChoice arr => arr a b -> arr [a] [b]
mapA f = arr listcase >>>
         (arr (const []) ||| (f *** mapA f >>> arr (uncurry (:))))
```

Comment: I'm still confused by your choice of title (to which the answer is a resounding 'yes') - would you care to expand your question a little for those of us who last used `Arrow`s in the bronze age?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think your `ArrowChoice` instance is correct.

Note that the `delay` function takes a stream and replaces the first element; critically, it doesn't treat all elements identically. Now, consider your definition of `Left`:

```
left (SF f) = SF $ map (either (\x -> Left . head $ f [x]) Right)
```

Observe that `f` is the guts of an entire stream function, and thus may behave differently depending on stream position. The `left` function then creates a new stream function that *maps a homogeneous* function over its stream, where each element is either passed through (for `Right`s) or lifted to a singleton list on which the input stream function is run.

Rather than `delay`, consider instead the following function:

```
skip = SF $ drop 1
```

This drops the first element of a stream entirely, and since `left` runs its input independently each time on a singleton list, this would filter out all `Left`s entirely! Probably not what you want.

Rather, you need to do something like partition the stream into its `Left` and `Right` components, apply the input stream function to the *entire* stream of `Left`s, then merge the lefts and rights back together in the same sequence they were in originally.

I get the impression that you're doing this as some sort of exercise so I won't spoil the fun by simply writing the solution out in full. But I will say that my code indeed gives `[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` on your example.

---

If you do want to see my test code, it's below. (shh, it's hiding)

> ```
>  instance ArrowChoice SF where
>      left (SF f) = SF $ \xs -> let (ls, rs) = partitionEithers xs 
>                                in merge xs (f ls) rs
>  
>  merge (Left  _:xs) (l:ls) rs = Left l  : merge xs ls rs
>  merge (Right _:xs) ls (r:rs) = Right r : merge xs ls rs
>  merge _ _ _ = []
> ```

Comment: @kizzx2: Neither did I, but it seemed appropriate here. I knew there was a "spoiler" feature, and the ~8 minutes or so between posting the answer and adding the hidden code is how long it took me to figure out how to make it display properly...